# Apex if statement to test if user has a company email address

Tags: unit-test, class, help

After some serious help, I've achieved what I was hoping to achieve in my code.  However, now I need to add one more piece.  Essentially, I need to test if the User being added has an email address that contains the string "@companyname.com" and if so, to assign it to a specific account.

Right now, the code will automatically assign every user that specific account.  To achieve my selective objective this is what I have tried:

1. Pattern and Matcher
2. IF(CONTAINS
3. LIKE %companyname%
4. Tearing my hair out

So far none of the above methods have been successful.

Here is the code in question.

```
public class UserContact {   
//Create the class and grab the IDs needed
 public static void createUserContact(set<ID> recordIDs){
//Grab all the required fields from user, essential to test class
    list<user> users = [SELECT ID, Firstname, Lastname, email, name, CommunityNickname, TimeZoneSidKey, LocaleSidKey, EmailEncodingKey, ProfileId, LanguageLocaleKey 
                        FROM user
                        WHERE ID in :recordIDs];  

    String accountName = 'Company Internal';
    "LIMIT 1" to avoid more than 1 record returning
     Account Accountx = [SELECT ID
                            FROM account
                           where Name = :accountName
                           LIMIT 1];      
     //Need to create an 'if' statement to test if the contact has a company internal email address, and if so,
     //to assign it the company internal account.
    //Create a list to hold the contacts being created
    List<Contact> contactsToCreate = new List<Contact>();
     //Iterate through each field we want to automatically populate
    for (user x: users){
        Contact userCon = new contact(
        AccountID = AccountX.id,
        FirstName = x.FirstName,
        LastName = x.LastName,
        email = x.Email);
        contactsToCreate.add(userCon);

    insert contactsToCreate;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try,

```
    string email= 'firstname123@gmail.com';


system.debug(email.endsWith('@gmail.com'));
```

This returns true when email contains the specific domain.

Comment: I did not...  In that scenario (excuse my noobness) would 'string' be a variable, or literally the word 'string'?  

I tried something similar, using 'user.email' in place of 'string' and it gave me an error that I could not reference a static object like that.

Comment: @DanielSassone It's literally the word `String`. It's calling the static method `endsWith()` on the `String` class. Here's a link to [the string class documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) that goes over all of the methods you can call.

Comment: @DerekF The method is not static.

Comment: Thank you!

I tried using this, and while the tests passed, even if the newly created user did not have an email that fit the criteria, it would still assign it the account name "Company Internal".  

I placed 'if(string.endsWith('@companyname.com')){'  Around "String accountname = 'Company Internal';"  and the Accountx query.

Comment: @Daniel Sassone I have edited my answer , Hope that helps

Comment: @AnuragA  It does!  But in this case, I need to modify my code to update the string 'email' to whatever the user's email is, then check it against that, correct?

Comment: Yes. Thats correct

Answer (score 1):

```
String accountName = 'Company Name';
String accountNameInternal = 'Company Internal';
"LIMIT 1" to avoid more than 1 record returning
 Account Accountx = [SELECT ID
                        FROM account
                       where Name = :accountNameInternal
                       LIMIT 1];
Account AccountCompanyName = [SELECT ID
                        FROM account
                       where Name = :accountName
                       LIMIT 1];
for (user x: users){
    Contact userCon = new contact(        
    AccountID = x.email.endsWith('@companyname.com')?AccountCompanyName.id:AccountX.id,
    FirstName = x.FirstName,
    LastName = x.LastName,
    email = x.Email);
    contactsToCreate.add(userCon);
}
insert contactsToCreate; // Move the DML statement out of for loop.
```

Here `AccountCompanyName` is the specific Account and `AccountX` is the generic Account. You should query for both account before hand itself.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  
I'll be trying this next, and in this case 'AccountCompanyName' is going to be the actual name of the account, not a variable named 'AccountCompanyName', right?

Comment: Updated my answer to include the account queries as well.